# Passing User Data Parameters via Pixel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I wish to pass user data parameters from Facebook's Pixel using fbq function and check whther the data passed is correct or not.

Two of the user data parameter - external_id and country aren't being passed but the first name, last name, phone number and email ID are getting passed with no issue whatsoever.

```
<!-- Meta Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '621326435358269',{
  'em': {{js - email}},         //Values will be hashed automatically by the pixel using SHA-256
  'fn': {{js - first_name}}, 
  'ln': {{js - last_name}},      
  'ph': {{js - phone_number}},
  'external_id': {{js - email}},
  'country': {{lookup - url - country - meta}}
});
fbq('set', 'agent', 'gtmss', '621326435358269');
fbq('track', {{FB_CONVERSIONS_API-621326435358269-Web-Variable-FBEventName}},{},{'eventID': {{FB_CONVERSIONS_API-621326435358269-Web-Variable-Event_ID_Constant}}});
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=621326435358269&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Meta Pixel Code -->
```

Test Events Preview screenshot

[image]

I know user data parameters can only be passed with **fbq(init)** call but why only **external_id** and **country** is not getting passed. I even tried "*`extern_id`*" name and the country_code is as per the Facebook formatting guidelines - *`lower-case two letter code`  *but it still doesnt work.

I tried the facebook tag template on GTM and it's also useless in this matter as Simo Ahava (The creator) said that -

> Advanced matching is only applied when the pixel is initialized, so these values will only be seen if this is the first FB tag for that pixel on the page. That’s a limitation of the fbevents.is library itself

Comment: You can try to console the object `{
  'em': {{js - email}},         //Values will be hashed automatically by the pixel using SHA-256
  'fn': {{js - first_name}}, 
  'ln': {{js - last_name}},      
  'ph': {{js - phone_number}},
  'external_id': {{js - email}},
  'country': {{lookup - url - country - meta}}
}` In the preview or debug mode and see if what is really inside the object